# Alternate to ugly \parallel and \sslash symbols in subscript mathmode

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amsmath, subscripts

I'm looking for a nicer "parallel" symbol that matches the `\perp` symbol, when used in subscripts.  Here's a MWE showing the `\parallel`, `\perp`, `\sslash` and two custom symbols (currently called `\para` and `\paral`):

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\newcommand*{\paral}{\scalebox{0.6}{$\slash\!\slash$}}

\newcommand*{\para}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{$\scalebox{0.8}{=}$}}

\begin{document}

Blabla:
\begin{equation}
     v_{\parallel \perp}v_{\sslash \perp}v_{\paral \perp}v_{\para \perp}.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Preview:

[image]

As any cat could see here, the first one (`\parallel`) is too high compared to the `\perp` symbol next to it.  I hate it and prefer to leave it to the dogs!  It causes ugly spacements problems especially in fractions.  The second one (`\sslash` in the second term) is not much better.  The third one (custom `\paral`) is a bit better but there's a vertical offset that annoys the cat in me.  The fourth one (`\para`) is much closer to the one I'm looking, which fits better to the `\perp` next to it (its size could be adjusted a bit, and there's also a vertical offset though).

So I'm wondering if there's a better solution that I'm unaware of.  What would you suggest to get the best looking parallel symbol in subscript position that would complement the nice `\perp` symbol in shape, size and readability?  How would you modify the macros I've defined in the code above?

Thank you very much and get a nice cat meal for free!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `\stretchrel` from the scalerel package.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\usepackage{scalerel}

\newcommand*{\paral}{\stretchrel*{\parallel}{\perp}}
\newcommand*{\Sslash}{\stretchrel*{\sslash}{\perp}}

\begin{document}

Blabla:
\begin{equation}
     v_{\parallel \perp}\quad\text{vs.}\quad v_{\paral \perp}
     \quad\text{and}\quad
     v_{\sslash \perp}\quad\text{vs.}\quad v_{\Sslash \perp}\;.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice.  May be the best solution...

Comment: Very very nice!!  Just wow!  Which one is better?  \Sslash or \paral?

Comment: @Cham Purrrrrrr

Comment: You'll get two free cat meals for this, ... and a mouse to play with...